# Remove page break lines from worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Microsoft Excel adds dashed lines to your worksheets when you use the print preview feature, as a way to adjust page breaks. When you leave print preview though, you can often be stuck with those annoying lines in your worksheet. How can you remove them from the worksheet?

For example, if you have an Excel worksheet, you go into Page Break Preview to see (and to set) where page breaks are in your worksheet for printing:

[image: Menu location for Page Break Preview]

In this example, the worksheet will print as 1 page that contains the contents of cells A1:C7

[image: Page Break Preview view]

The issue occurs when you use the View ribbon to turn off Page Break Preview, and go back to Normal view of the worksheet. Then you see these annoying lines drawn in the worksheet where the page breaks are located. They appear as either dashed or solid lines.

[image: Normal view showed lines around page breaks]

These lines look like cell borders, although they are not. How do you disable them once they are turned on?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These lines are indeed not cell borders, and are only visible in Excel as a guide for where the page breaks are located. Microsoft Office Support suggests [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-ad3dc726-beec-4a4c-861f-ed640612bdc2#bm7) to clear them:

- Click Options in the File menu
- In the Advanced category, scroll down to the Display options for this worksheet section, and clear the Show page breaks check box

Repeat this procedure for each worksheet in your workbook that contains print preview lines.

This manual procedure can be time consuming if you have multiple worksheets with this issue. In that case, you can use this VBA macro to remove print preview lines for all worksheets in your workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub disableAllPageBreaks()

  Dim ws as Worksheet

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
  Next ws

End Sub
```