# How to disable page breaks from showing on all Excel pages using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I work with many Excel sheets with many tabs and I am not able to permanently disable the page break view, I have to select each tab and then go into `Settings > Advanced` and disable the `View page breaks` checkbox. Adding a new tab in the sheet puts back the page breaks, regardless of this setting.

I know there are some VBA scripts that disable on multiple pages, but then you need to add the VBA to each sheet, which is also time consuming. I'm looking for a method that disables the `view page break` checkbox, permanently, from any Excel sheet on all tabs. Alternatively, maybe there is some registry setting that disables this checkbox by default?

Preferably through PowerShell, so I can just run it from PowerShell CLI on any sheet and have it disable this. Perhaps something like this:

```
./disablePageBreakView.ps1 SomeExcelFile.xlsx
```

---

UPDATE: **2023-12-25**

If it is possible to convert a VBS script to powershell, we could use the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339966/1147688):

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub disableAllPageBreaks()
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
  Next ws
End Sub
```

---

**References**:

- [removing all page breaks such that excel>pdf only prints on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885507/removing-all-page-breaks-such-that-excelpdf-only-prints-on-page)
- [Excel Page Break Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531085/excel-page-break-macro)
- [Remove page break lines from worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339965/remove-page-break-lines-from-worksheet)
- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-startup-folders
- [2] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19

Comment: I rarely have to use Excel nowadays but it sounds like you have a general setting you may change instead of each individual tab in each individual file - something like the `normal.dot` for Word. Have you tried this: [Customize how Excel starts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19)? If that does not help you may evaluate the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel).

Comment: Page breaks will automatically be added if you go outside the print range.  Did you try to "Clear Print Area"

Comment: Please note, I'm not looking for a UI solution, as it doesn't work. I'm looking for a scriptable solution that can be run on multiple Excel files, and doesn't need any additional excel packages, or pasting VBA into the sheet itself. Or a solution that *permanently* disable the showing of the (automatically added) page breaks (on **all** tabs, regardless of what Excel file you open.

Comment: ...and for those who vote to close the question, please provide a comment here and explain why, or what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: Have you tried the module [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel)?

Comment: Hi Olaf, no because I don't see how importing a new posh package with ~265 powershell scripts is going to solve my problem.

Comment: Just found the github repo for [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).

Comment: I'm confused actually. You want to treat Excel files but you don't want to try a PowerShell module desinged to make the work with Excel files easier?  ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- The code below is the **PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent of the VBA code in your question**; it accepts the literal file paths of one more workbooks, either as direct arguments or via `Get-ChildItem` pipeline input.
- This this **may or may not *persistently* change the setting** for you.

  - In my tests based on Office 2019, the setting was not only *off* by default, but changing it *persistently* failed - whether via the Excel GUI itself or via the function below. While toggling the setting via the Excel GUI did register as a "dirtying" the workbook, i.e. necessitating *saving* it, on reopening it had reverted to the off state.

```bash
function Disable-PageBreaks {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string[]] $LiteralPath
  )
  begin {
    $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  }
  process {
    & { # Run in a child scope, to auto-release the COM references.
      foreach ($p in Convert-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath) {
        if (-not $?) { return } # skip nonexistent files.
        $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($LiteralPath)
        foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
          $ws.DisplayPageBreaks = $false
        }
        $wb.Save()
        $wb.Close()
      }
    }
  }
  end {
    $xl.Quit()
    $xl = $null
    # Note: The excel.exe process should disappear after a few seconds.
  }
}
```

Comment: I also managed to create a similar function in posh and like you, I was also using Office Pro 2019, and noticed that the script ran, but after saving and reopen, the setting had reverted. I then tried on another company Office365, and the setting seemed to work on all pages (unlike the other version), but I believe the company has a policy implemented and possibly some other way of starting up Excel with some pre-set profile. I can't really wrap my head around where Excel is getting fed these settings and when/where/how it is activated or not. Different versions doing different things.

Comment: Nice way you use a child-process to autorelease the COM object. I was using: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)|Out-Null`.

Comment: Thanks, @not2qubit - for background info on the COM-object-releasing technique, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423449/45375).

Comment: Hmm, I think it was a mistake. I deleted my previous comments to avoid confusion. Instead I found [xlPageBreakNone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpagebreak), that can be set to not show automatically generated page-breaks on pages,as stated: "*Page breaks are not inserted on the worksheet.*"

Comment: Thanks, @not2qubit - so does this setting persist for you?